# Helpers do Laravel não funcionam em modo produção hospedagem compartilhada

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Tenho uma aplicação Laravel 5.6 hospedada na Ycorn, lá, por ser compartilhada, não possuo acesso SSH, o que dificulta muito implementação do *framework*.

Com isso, os *helpers* `{{asset()}}` e `{{url()}}` não encontram meus arquivos CSS, JS, etc. Isso está me causando muita dor de cabeça, pois a aplicação não funciona 100%.

Mas, exemplo o `url()` funciona para rotas assim como `route()`, porém para acessar arquivos tenho que fazer algo como

```
href="url('public/images/'.$imagem)"
```

Já li que pode ser `.htacess`, mas não consegui.

Na hospedagem o site fica na pasta `public_html`, então movi meus arquivos da pasta `/public/` do Laravel para o `/public_html` e ajustei para funcionar.

Aqui esta meu `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Já tentei por o `RewriteBase` `/public` `/public_html` mas nada funcionou

Answer (score -1):

Tenta seguir as orientações desse link: https://medium.com/@luisdalmolin/como-fazer-deploy-de-uma-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-laravel-em-uma-hospedagem-compartilhada-bc114ee2cbb9

Principalmente a parte abaixo, assim não precisa mover seu public para o public_html:

> 8- Criar um link simbólico para a pasta public
>
> Aqui está o real motivo de você precisar um acesso SSH a hospedagem.
>   Precisamos dizer ao servidor que quando o usuário acessar a pasta
>   public_html (ou www, ou qualquer outra coisa que seja), ele na verdade
>   vai acessar ~/apps/seusite.com/public. Para isto, vamos criar um link
>   simbólico.
>
> $ cd ~ && ln -s ~/apps/seusite.com/public public_html Teoricamente,
>   neste momento seu site já deve estar funcionando corretamente (A não
>   ser que você esteja na Locaweb, aí provavelmente vai ter que ver o
>   próximo passo)